# 3+ month delay in reviewing the revision of paper, what can we do?

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors

I had submitted a paper in an ISI journal, i.e. in Taylor and Francis. The first submission date of the manuscript was `30-may-2014`. We received the first revision result on `27-July-2014`. Hopefully, the result of reviewing our paper was optimistic as the paper status was `accept with change`; we had only some minor comments. We submitted the answer of revision on `15 Aug`. They didn’t reply our revision yet. How can we write to them to review our paper faster?
Note: Its 2-Dec Today.

Answer (score 5):

Aug 15 to at least Dec 2 seems like a very long period for a decision based on a minor revision. Particularly since the procedure earlier seems to be very timely. Sending an e-mail to the handling editor seems in perfect order. There may of course be some natural reason for the delay but after more than three months you should certainly enquire.

As for the content of your request just make is short, to the point and polite. Do not assume anything or be unfairly judgemental, you do not, yet, know the reasons for the delay. If you have some "excuse" for why you are extra anxious to get a response, please mention it. This could be that you need to show your updated publication list for applications or for some other official reason. This will of course not mean you receive special treatment but will make the editor aware of the delay and the possible effects it may have. But, a short e-mail will suffice.

Comment: @Electricman "I need this paper to finish my Phd" sounds like you are trying to influence the decision, while wanting an up to date publication list prior to your examination is a little more neutral.

Comment: @Electricman we are really not a proof reading service. Your letter seems reasonable, but I would ask someone to proof read it for you.